# Using mysqli and prepared statements I want to return the column results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been trying to return the results of a single column into variables using mysqli prepared statements.

I have no problem returning the results of a row once I make my query, but I want to store the vertical column results. Is it possible?

```
$sql = "SELECT submachine FROM parts WHERE machine = ?;";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['q']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($one, $two, $three);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Vertical? You mean you want to take the value from each resulting row?

Comment: I want to take the values descending down one column

Comment: Just `fetchAll` into an array. Creating *n* variables dynamically is not sensible.